# AngularStrap and Google maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-strap

What is the best integration Google Maps with AngularJS to be compatible with **AngularStrap**?
I just found two good choices:

- Angularjs-Google-Maps (https://ngmap.github.io/)
- Angular-Google-Maps (http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/) - looks like angular-ui part

I appreciate any advice in this subject.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use https://ngmap.github.io/ and I'm happy with it.

Quite good support and very quick setup.